# Creating login session via CURL

Tags: php, login, curl

Using the following code I experienced some problems: Login works but every link in the dashboard I will click will follow into the 404 not found page. It seems that there won't be a working session created?

```
$username="admin";
$password="admin";
$url="http://www.yourdomain.com/";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = "log=". $username ."&pwd=". $password ."&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=". $url ."wp-admin/&testcookie=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "wp-login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "wp-admin/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
exit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure its a session issue, i think it has to do with the fact that WordPress Dashboard uses relative links.

A quick hackish fix would be to add

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURL_COOKIEFILE, '');  // Enables session support
```

Then, add this after closing the curl handler redirect to the actual dashbard location:

```
curl_close($ch);
header('location: blog/wordpress/wp-admin/');
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bainternet...good answer, I have tried your way and there are some error which I want to comment

> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt'); missed OPT

and for redirection it is adding above url and to avoid that you can use

> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'log='.urlencode($log).'&pwd='.urlencode($password).'&redirect_to='.urlencode($redirect));

here u can provide redirect url as per your need to any part of wordpress admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

The key change is that I removed the parameter called "testcookie" from my post string.

Note: add your website instead of "mywordpress" and username and password in the below code

```
$curl = curl_init();

//---------------- generic cURL settings start ----------------
$header     = array(
      "Referer: https://mywordpress/wp-login.php",
"Origin: https://mywordpress",
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
      );


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
//---------------- generic cURL settings end ----------------



$url = 'https://mywordpress/wp-login.php';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$post = 'log=username&pwd=password&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=https%3A%2F% mywordpress%2Fwp-admin%2F';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$output = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close ($curl);

echo ($output)
```